# Pandas DataFrame: Cost calculation according to the tariff of each carrier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculation

My dataframe has columns like: Region, UF, volume.  Each row in the table is a product, which will be shipped to a certain region and has a certain weight and price.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        data = \[('Vila Velha', 'ES', 220, 2300),
                ('Leio', 'ES',12, 100),
                ('São Paulo', 'SP',12, 200),
                ('Lauro de Freitas', 'BA',5, 400),
                ('Fortaleza', 'CE',14, 500)
                \],

columns=\['Region','UF', 'Weight','Price of the Product']
```

In addition to this dataframe, I have another one that contains information such as: Which carriers deliver to a certain region.

```
RegionT = ["Vila Velha","Leio","São Paulo","Lauro de Freitas","Fortaleza"]
TrUF = ['ES','ES','SP,'BA','CE']
Tr1 = ['Evidência','Termaco','Termaco','Evidência']
Tr2 = ['0','Leite Express','Leite Express','0']
Tr3 = ['Sudoeste','0','0','0']
Tr4 = ['0','0','0','0','0']

Transportadoras = pd.DataFrame(
    data = zip(RegionT,TrUF,Tr1,Tr2,Tr3,Tr4),
        columns=["Region","UF","Transp. 1","Transp. 2","Transp. 3","Transp. 4"])
```

We have that a region has more than one carrier and 0 represents no carrier. Finally, I have a price table for each carrier, an example:

```
#Sudoeste
Location = ["Capital","Interior"]
UF = ['ES','RJ']
Minimum_shipping_up_to_10kg = [47.40,48.34]
MinShipping_bettwen_10_to20 = [57.40, 58.34]
MinShipping_bettwen_20_to30 = [67.40, 68.34]
Shipping_after_50kg = [0.710, 0.22]
Toll = [2.83,2.83]
GRIS = [0.12,0.12]
Tax = [3.36,8.52]

Sudoeste = pd.DataFrame(
    data = zip(Location,UF,Minimum_shipping_up_to_10kg,MinShipping_bettwen_10_to20,MinShipping_bettwen_20_to30,Shipping_after_50kg,Toll,GRIS,Tax),
        columns=["Location","UF","Minimun Shipping to 10","Bettwen 10 to 20","Bettwen 20 to 30","After 50","Toll","GRIS","Tax"])
```

Taking the first line of my dataframe as an example, to calculate your freight according to the southwest table: containing the information that it has 220 weight and has a price of 2300.

According to the Sudoeste table, your price should be:

Minimum shipping up to 30: 67.40

After 50kg: (220-30)*0.710

Toll - fraction of 100kgs(Formula in Excel): "ROUND(220/100;0)*2.83"

GRIS (the values ​​in the table are in percentage): 2300*0.12%

Tax: 3.36

Formula = 67.40 + (220-30)*0.710 + (2300)*0.12% + (220/100)*2.83 + 3.36

Formula = 67.40 + 134.9 + 2300*0.12% + 5.66 + 3.36 = 214.08

Therefore, the total freight will be the sum of all these values: 214.08, that is, to transport this item to the Vila Velha region, it will cost 214.08 by the Sudoeste carrier.

How can I make these accounts in python? Where do the calculation for each carrier, if any, and list the result in a new column.

I don't know how to do these calculations in python.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that has your pricing logic like the following so you can *apply* this function to your dataframe row wise:

```
def calculate_price(row):
    '''
        Calculates total freight cost
    '''
    w = row['weight']
    p = row['price']
    rate = 0
    total_cost = 0
    griss = row['GRIS']
    toll = row['Toll']
    tax = row['Tax']
    if (w <= 10):
        rate = row['Minimun Shipping to 10']
    if (w > 10 and w <=20):
        rate = row['Bettwen 10 to 20']
    if (w > 20 and w <=30):
        rate = row['Bettwen 20 to 30']
    if (w > 50):
        rate = row['After 50']
    
    total_cost = (rate * w) + (p*griss)+(w/100)*toll+tax
        
    return total_cost
```

Be carefull with the names of your columns, if you change your column names then modify the function.

Add the columns to your dataframe so it replicates to each row like

```
sudoeste_df['weight']=220
sudoeste_df['price']=2300
```

then apply the function

```
sudoeste_df['total_freight']=sudoeste_df.apply(calculate_price,axis=1)
```

Checkout this article:
[http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html][1]

Enjoy python

Comment: Thank you very much  how can I add a column in my Df that displays this total cost value for the sudoeste carrier?

Comment: This will add a new column "total_freight" to the Dataframe: sudoeste_df['total_freight']=sudoeste_df.apply(calculate_price,axis=1). When you use a column between brackets that doest not exist, it will be added to the Dataframe. Checkout the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html

Comment: But it applied a New column in my southwest dataframs, not in my dataframs df

Comment: Join the Dataframes , then apply the function.  final_dataframe = df.set_index("UF").join(Sudoeste.set_index("UF"),lsuffix="_df",rsuffix="_sudo",how="inner")`  final_dataframe["total_cost"]=final_dataframe.apply(calculate_price,axis=1)